# Is there a Fluent NHibernate way to index all foreign keys without coding it?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, conventions

Is that possible, with a convention maybe?  I have hundreds of tables and a myriad of relationships, I'd like all foreign keys to be indexed and I'd hate to have to code that.

**UPDATE**

With @Vadim's help, I was able to do this:

```
var fkIndexConvention = ConventionBuilder.Reference.Always(x =>
    x.Index(string.Format("ix{0}_{1}_{2}", x.Class.Name, x.Property.Name,
    Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty))));
```

... and then add it to my fluent configuration:

```
var fluent = Fluently.Configure(config)
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.Conventions.Add(fkIndexConvention));
```

... and the world was a better place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about using the hbm2ddl tool and SchemaExport.

All you should need to do is set a Reference convention. Since `IManyToOneInstance` hides the Foreign key, you should be able to cast the instance to an `IManyToOneInspector`.

```
ConventionBuilder.Reference.Always(x => x.Index(((IManyToOneInspector)x).ForeignKey + "Index"));
```

Comment: In this context, `x.ForeignKey` is a void method, not a property.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Hmm, must be the version of Fluent you are using. The latest from github has ForeignKey as a string property https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Conventions/Inspections/IManyToOneInspector.cs

Comment: Are you sure the lambda expression here represents an `IManyToOneInspector`?  I pulled my library from Nuget about 3-4 months ago, and this code is 2 years old, it seems odd that this would be so out-of-date.

Comment: Ah, I see, it looks like IManyToOneInstance hides the property. I suppose you could cast it. I've modified my answer.

Comment: This seems to build OK, but adding the convention reveals that the Foreign Key name is for all entries.... so this may be close, and I may just need to define a fk naming convention.

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to work for uni-directional one-to-many relationships eg when the parent references a collection of children, but each child does not reference its parent.

Comment: @rich.okelly use `ConventionBuilder.HasMany` instead with the `IOneToManyCollectionInspector`

Comment: @Vadim That won't compile, `Index` is a property of `IOneToManyCollectionInspector`. The nearest method I can see: `x => x.Index.Column("ColumnName")` seems to do nothing